# Disable access to jsp files on apache server

Tags: jsp, url, path

I'm sorry if I ask a question that's been asked before, but I could not find my answer on the website after a few hours of research.
My problem is that I'm using tomcat on my server, and everything works fine, except that I can access all the jsp and jspf pages on the website by directly typing the path to the file in the url, but this is a very bad security. I would like to only be able to type in the address of the website, if any subdirectory is called then should redirect to the base url.

I tried to do this with a RedirectRule, but could never get it to work (will always allow access).

I also tried with  but it still didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in `/WEB-INF` folder. Then they're only accessible by `RequestDispatcher` in a controlling servlet or by `<jsp:include>`.

Comment: Thanks! so I tried to move the jsp folder under WEB-INF/ folder, but now I cannot see anything on the website. I think it comes from the fact that I include my pages by doing /jsp/..., do you know a way to make it work without needing to change the path everywhere to WEB-INF/jsp/... ? thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: You need to change the paths. Just do a *find-and-replace-in-all-files* in your editor.

Comment: It took me a bit more time than just this, but it worked! thanks a lot

Comment: I actually found a better solution (I think): add some filter mapping rules in the web.xml file or the project, and then in the Filter class just check for a value (like set in the session) and redirect if the expected result is not reached.